# CSS transition: animate parent on children hover

Tags: css, attributes, jquery-animate, parent-child

Normally, I would select the parent and add a hover pseudo class:

```
parent {
    opacity: 0.7;
    transition-duration: .2s;
}

parent:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

But there are too many diffrent parent elements, with diffrent tags and classes.
I only know that every parent have only children with the `[color]` attribut.

```
(parent "which have" > [color]) {
    opacity: 0.7;
    transition-duration: .2s;
}

(parent "which have" > [color]):hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Is there something like a parent selector in CSS3 (CSS4: '!')?
Or is there another way to animate a parent on children hover?

Thanks for help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS parent selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Comment: You wouldn't need a parent selector as the hover would apply to both the parent and the child anyway.

Comment: There is no parent selector in CSS. However, there are some ways around it, depending on what you're trying to do. Check out the 'inherit' property: http://joshnh.com/2012/10/25/dont-forget-the-css-value-inherit/

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little bit ambigius but let me guess what you mean and try to give you a solution;

you have parent div element with color attr (assume it is red) and you want it's child element have style in hover state.

```
div[style~='color:red']>p:hover{
 //your code goes here
}
```

but your color must be defined as inline style otherwise you need to look to other attr like data attribute data-selparent='yes'.